# For what values of p is given series convergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series

The given series is $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\left(\frac{{(\ln n)}^{p}}{n}\right)$.And the question is for what values of $p$ series converges.
I try a little bit but don't know whether it is right?I try to check values of p for which series is absolutely convergent and then by using integral test I think $p<-1$.But when I use alternating series test I think $p$ will take all negative real values and $0$ also. But I am getting feeling that $p$ will take some or all positive values also as $\lim_{n\to\infty}{(\ln n)}^{p}/n=0$. Please correct me.

Comment: this is right, it must be $p+1<0$

Comment: but for p=0 and 1 also it is convergent by alternating series test

Comment: ur right, all real value will do

Comment: @lion..I am feeling all real value will do but only problem I think is for large positive value of p, $a(n)$ will not be monotonically decreasing for few starting terms..so will it satisfy alternating series test in that case..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- For the absolute convergence, the series $\;\displaystyle\sum_{n\ge2}\frac{\log^p n}n=\sum_{n\ge2}\frac1{n\log^{-p}n}$ is a *Bertrand's series*, known to converge if and only if $-p>1$.
- For the semi-convergence, apply *Leibniz' criterion* for alternating series. We only have to determine for which values of $p$ $\;\dfrac{\log^p n}n$ is eventually monotonically decreasing.

So consider the function $f(x)=\dfrac{\log^p x}x$. Its derivative is
$$f'(x)=\frac{p\log^{p-1}x-\log^px}{x^2}=\frac{\log^{p-1\!}x\,(p-\log x)}{x^2}$$
and, if $x>1$, it has the sign of $p-\log x$. Thus the function is decreasing if and only if 
$$$\log x>p\iff x >\mathrm e^{\mkern2mu p} $$
As a conclusion the sequence is eventually decreasing for all  values of $p$, hence the alternating series converges for all $p$.

Comment: Idea of derivative was good.. i think in hurry you forget to put ${x^{2}}$ in denominator of derivative..

Comment: Oh! yes. It's fixed now. Thanks for pointing it!

Comment: sorry but one last doubt..from that second last iff statement how you arrive at the conclusion that all positive values of $p$ will also work..means do you mean that if p is large enough there will be $x$ such that $log x$ will get greater than $p$ after that point .

Comment: I mean that whatever $p$, if $x$ is large enough, $ \log x >p$ (and I give the precise meaning of ‘large enough’ in terms of $p$).

Comment: Ok...got it...!